# GKE Kubernetes network policy allowing other node IPs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy, gke-networking

I have a GKE cluster (1.16) with 2+ nodes and a GKE Ingress HTTPS load balancer.
I'm deploying several namespaces on it.
I want to deny all traffic between namespaces, so I'm using the recipe found [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/04-deny-traffic-from-other-namespaces.md).
However, according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#working_with_https_load_balancer_health_checks) (my externalTrafficPolicy is using the default value of `Cluster`):

> If externalTrafficPolicy is not set to Local, the network policy must also allow connections from other node IPs in the cluster.

How to *allow connections from other node IPs in the cluster* in my NetworkPolicy definition?
My current definition is:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 35.191.0.0/16
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 130.211.0.0/22
```

Comment: You want to deny traffic between namespaces, but want to keep traffic from public to you cluster? Or do you want to isolate it like `Private cluster`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE nodes communicate over a private address space, so you can allow `10.0.0.0/8` (or be more specific).

Comment: Thank you. If one wants to be more specific, the gcloud compute subnetworks endpoint provides with the values per region.